# How to take CSS property from user using Js

Tags: javascript, html, css

my page consist of the following:

1. input type text
2. button
3. paragraph

I want the user to enter the CSS code in the input field and then when He click on the button the code must be applied to the paragraph.

example:
the user entered `color:red` at the input.
he clicked the button.
the code which he entered (color:red) should be applied at the Paragraph

I made this code to do it but there is a problem in it and I, think it's about concatenation so code. Can someone help me on that?

here is my code -- js line number 10

```js
var Inpt = document.getElementById("Inpt"),
    Par = document.getElementById("Par"),
    Btn = document.getElementById("Btn"),
    Val;

Btn.onclick = function () {
    "use strict";
    Val = Inpt.value;
    Val = Val.split(":");
    Par.style.Val[0] = Val[1];
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Inpt">
<button id="Btn"> Apply</button>
<p id="Par">This Is The Paragraph</p>
```

Comment: `Par.style[Val[0]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have my answer, I changed a little the name of the variables, but it works like charm:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="Inpt">
<button id="Btn"> Apply</button>
<p id="Par">This Is The Paragraph</p>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var input = document.getElementById("Inpt"),
    parameter = document.getElementById("Par"),
    button = document.getElementById("Btn"),
    value;

button.onclick = function () {
    "use strict";
    value = input.value;
    value = value.split(":");
    parameter.style[value[0]] = value[1];
};
```

Jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/wj8o4uq8/

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you, I tried it but I keep seeing this error in console:         Unexpected token [

Comment: I solved a little typo, still used Btn instead of button. Also i added the link of a jsfiddle to check it working properly. Can you share us again the full error displayed in the console, please? Thanks.

Comment: it applies only one style per click, check my answer

Comment: It applies to every style, try for example background-color:blue;

Comment: what if I want to apply 2 styles, for example, color and font-size?

Comment: You can apply one and then the other separatedly. But if you want to apply them together you need a loop inside your function.

Comment: @Albert Vila Canela you don't need it, check my answer

Comment: @ivamax9 you're using native methods, which are more efficient than splitting a string into array, I would rather use your solution than mine. Good job for sure!

Answer (score 1):

Try to input this value: `color:red;`

If you want multiple styles: `color:red;font-size:20px;`

```js
var Inpt = document.getElementById("Inpt"),
    Par = document.getElementById("Par"),
    Btn = document.getElementById("Btn"),
    Val;

Btn.onclick = function () {
    "use strict";
    Val = Inpt.value;
    Par.setAttribute("style", Val);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Inpt">
<button id="Btn"> Apply</button>
<p id="Par">This Is The Paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Inpt = document.getElementById("Inpt"),
    Par = document.getElementById("Par"),
    Btn = document.getElementById("Btn"),
    Val;

Btn.onclick = function () {
    "use strict";
    Val = Inpt.value;
    Par.style.cssText = Val;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Inpt">
<button id="Btn"> Apply</button>
<p id="Par">This Is The Paragraph</p>
```